# How to get a parameter from a complex xml text in shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I have a quite complex xml text in one row about alerts's datas. I would like to get the ID of alert named "emergency". Now here are just two alerts, but the text is dinamic so there could be more, so I have to create a command what get the ID and only require the name of the alert. IDs and names are both unique. Here is the text:

```
<get_alerts_response status_text="OK" status="200"><alert id="9028c78d-5e77-4adb-af4c-cb7dcf1ee3dc"><owner><name>aron</name></owner><name>Befejezve</name><comment>Vége a scannek</comment><creation_time>2014-07-01T07:49:41Z</creation_time><modification_time>2014-07-02T09:04:16Z</modification_time><writable>1</writable><in_use>1</in_use><permissions><permission><name>Everything</name></permission></permissions><user_tags><count>0</count></user_tags><condition>Always</condition><event>Task run status changed<data>Done<name>status</name></data></event><method>Email<data>2<name>notice</name></data><data>neferien@gmail.com<name>from_address</name></data><data>6c248850-1f62-11e1-b082-406186ea4fc5<name>notice_attach_format</name></data><data>centrifuga.uranium@gmail.com<name>to_address</name></data><data>8307<name>defense_center_port</name></data><data><name>pkcs12</name></data><data><name>defense_center_ip</name></data></method></alert><alert id="2401db72-043d-46e4-b600-ada35f7f9cc1"><owner><name>aron</name></owner><name>emergency</name><comment></comment><creation_time>2014-07-21T13:37:25Z</creation_time><modification_time>2014-07-21T13:37:25Z</modification_time><writable>1</writable><in_use>0</in_use><permissions><permission><name>Everything</name></permission></permissions><user_tags><count>0</count></user_tags><condition>Severity at least<data>5.5<name>severity</name></data></condition><event>Task run status changed<data>Done<name>status</name></data></event><method>Email<data>sally@example.org<name>to_address</name></data><data>bob@example.org<name>from_address</name></data></method></alert><filters id=""><term>first=1 rows=-1 sort=name</term><keywords><keyword><column>first</column><relation>=</relation><value>1</value></keyword><keyword><column>rows</column><relation>=</relation><value>-1</value></keyword><keyword><column>sort</column><relation>=</relation><value>name</value></keyword></keywords></filters><sort><field>name<order>ascending</order></field></sort><alerts max="-1" start="1"></alerts><alert_count>2<filtered>2</filtered><page>2</page></alert_count></get_alerts_response>
```

I think I should do something like this, just this is too difficult at my level:

1. Find the place  where is the alert name (using variable) in the text (now "emergency")
2. Look for the first text "alert id="" before the alert name.
3. Get the next 34 character from there.

Thanks you very much if you can tell me how to do this or if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "<alert id=\""; FS = "\"" } /<name>emergency<\/name>/ { print $1 }' file
```

Output:

```
2401db72-043d-46e4-b600-ada35f7f9cc1
```

And here's another version as requested:

```
awk -v name="emergency" 'BEGIN { RS = "<alert id=\""; FS = "\"" } $0 ~ "<name>" name "</name>" { print $1 }' file
```

Comment: May I ask you how can I replace the "emergency" to a variable? I tryed: **awk -v var="emergency" 'BEGIN { RS = "<alert id=\""; FS = "\"" } /<name>var<\/name>/ { print $1 }'** but didn't work. awk is looks great just I don't know yet, how it works.

Comment: The full command was: **GetAlertID="$(omp -X "<get_alerts/>" | awk -v var="emergency" 'BEGIN { RS = "<alert id=\""; FS = "\"" } /<name>var<\/name>/ { print $1 }')"** the first part is the command to get the xml text, if I don't use the variable it is works nicely.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thanks again, now I understand the mechanics of it! I failed so many time, and it wasn't even difficult :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do that using regular expressions. However, you can (i.e. I don't mean that you specially can't do that, it is simply theoretically impossible) not correctly parse XML using regular expressions. XML is a context-free language, which is more expressive than a grammar based on regular expressions. Please see the Chomsky hierarchy for more details.

Hence, it is better (and easier and more stable) to use a proper XML parser. As I am most familiar with [BaseX](http://basex.org) (full disclousure: I am also associated with the project) I will use it.

When using the zip version, you can simple run the file `bin/basex`. What you want to do is a quite simple XPath expression and if you want to run it from the command line or a shell script the following should do. I assume you data is a file named `alert.xml`, of course you could also pass it in as a string from standard input.

```
basex -i alert.xml -q '//alert[name = "emergency"]/@id/string()'
```